# IntegerField automatically set to size of FileField

Tags: python, django

I have some model with FileField and a bunch of validators

```
class VideoContent(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='video_files', validators=[validate_file_extension, validate_file_size])
    size = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

Is there any way to make size be calculated automatically depending on the size of file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`FileField.size`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.size) attribute, which is set by default.

Your file size validator should look like:

```
def validate_file_size(value):
    if value.size > 1048576:  # Larger than 1MB
        raise ValidationError(u'%s file is too big' % value.name)
```

You can also rewrite models `save()` to set your `VideoContent.size` value when object is saved:

```
class VideoContent(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.size = self.file.size
        super(VideoContent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.size = self.file.size
```